# Tcl script for getting windows service is exist or not

Tags: windows-services, tcl

I want to check whether windows service is already installed or not by using tcl script.
note that i am using ActiveTcl.8.6.7 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `registry` package (standard on Windows) can be used to look in the place where the services are actually set.

```
package require registry
set services [registry keys {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services}]
if {$yourServiceName in $services} {
    puts "It is installed"
} else {
    puts "No $yourServiceName in [join $services ,]"
}
```

(*Check* that this works for you! I'm on the wrong OS to test it for you…)

Comment: in windows, showing error can't read "$servicename": no such variable.

Comment: Probably you should set `$servicename` before you execute that script.